# Calculating Cache miss rate - set associative

Tags: caching, assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

Piece of MIPS code:

```
.data
first-node : .word 10,next-node
next-node: .......
.text
la $s0,first-node
move $s1,$zero
loop:
la $t0,0($s0)
add $s1,$s1,$t0
lw $s0,4($s0)
bne $s0,$zero,loop
```

we got list of 4096 nodes,

Cache one-way

16 set

Block size: 128 byte

Virtual Memory with page size of 4KB

**1)** Find out the miss rate of the cache

- The miss rate first 16 operation? 
  **The answer:**4/4+2 (4 because there are 4 instrations in the loop and 2 before loop) - 4/6 = 66 %
- the miss rate 17th Iteration
  **The answer:**

1/6 (1 because it loads a new tree (I think) and 6 is total instrations) = 17%

- The miss rate 18th - 32th iteration?
  **The answer:**

0/6 (I didn't understand why 0 if we have to load the next tree) = 0%

- And the total miss rate?**The answer:**
  4*16+1*15/16*16*6 = 5% (This part I coudn't understand)

**2)** How many page fault were executed? 
**The answer:**
9 page fault

**3)** What is the miss rate in TLB?
**The answer:**
9/6*4096 0,03%

We answered all those questions in the class but, I didn't understand many of them can somebody please explain me?

Also What will be the difference between the one-way and 2-way? If it's bigger should be less miss rate,yes? the problem is how to calculate?